# Grails 1.0.3 console reports 'premature end of file'

Tags: grails, groovy

Browsing to a dynamic web page built using Grails version 1.0.3 the console log shows the following errors for each page request:

```
[Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file.
```

How do I stop this error from appearing for each request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log entry occurs when http requests are made from Firefox 3 browsers.

The workaround on Grails 1.0.3 is to open Config.groovy in your project and find the following:

```
grails.mime.types = [ html: ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
xml: ['text/xml', 'application/xml'], ...
```

The second line above, pertaining to xml should be removed.

This is a GRAILS 1.0.3 bug that has been resolved, see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3088 for full details.

Answer (score 12):

This bug was already fixed:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3088

> Premature end of file
>
> Affects Version/s:  1.0.3
>   Fix Version/s:  [1.0.4](http://web.archive.org/web/20080914033743/http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS/fixforversion/14156)
>
> ...Just a few implementation notes. We were defaulting to a q value of 0, which is incorrect according to the spec. So we now default to 1.0 which gives the correct precedence order in Firefox 3, but incorrect in Firefox 2. However, more specific XML types like application/xhtml+xml now take precendence over less specific ones if they have the same q value so this fixes the issue in Firefox 2...

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to a 1.0.4 snapshot is probably the best way to deal with this issue.  Check out the instructions under "Grails Development Builds" at [the Grails Download page](http://grails.org/Download).

It can also be ignored without too much difficulty.