# In Grails, getting [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Don't know why am I getting this error,But from my research over issue I found that having an in-place plugin with plugin.xml of 0 bytes is causing this issue. But in my in-place plugin there is no such plugin.xml because we don't want to have one.

Though I tried adding plugin.xml with some valid xml data in it,I was still getting same issue

Issue is, when i run my application and try hitting some url, I get below error / message which is  less descriptive more confusing:-

```
Getting [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file
Getting [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file
Getting [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file
```

I am using **grails version:-** - 2.3.8

Is it some bug or I am missing something while creating an in-place plugin?

Also, I Managed to look at JIRA for logged grails issues  as well.There they are saying corrected for 1.0.4 [JIRA 3088](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3088) and [JIRA 10108](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10108).

Stackoverflow also have a similar question put on but for different version of grails.[premature end of file 1.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136098/grails-1-0-3-console-reports-premature-end-of-file)

Finally, I looked at DefaultAcceptHeaderParser,DefaultAcceptHeaderParser and MimeType files in grails source to see if I get something. In some place, i remember it was mentioned that there is some default value that is missing while it read xmls, but that i believe was covered in above JIRA raised issues.

Comment: have you checked the target dir for empty .xml files?  and check, that your `BuildConfig.goovy` is setup (like newer version do) to keep all files in the target-dir (e.g. `grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"`

Comment: @cfrick I tried to check for such xml.No such xml is there.But i found a folder null, i tried deleting it but still facing same issue